Error: "Invalid build configuration" using mongodb-driver-kotlin-coroutine:5.2.0 in Android
I am working on an Android project where I need to use MongoDB with Kotlin coroutines. I added the following dependency in my build.gradle:

implementation "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-kotlin-coroutine:5.2.0"

However, when I try to build the project, I get the following error:

Invalid build configuration. Attempt to create a global synthetic for
‘Record desugaring’ without a global-synthetics consumer.

What I've tried so far:
I double-checked the gradle file and ensured all dependencies are updated.
Tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Attempted different versions of the MongoDB driver.
Verified the desugaring configurations.
My environment:
Android Studio:  Koala | 2024.1.1
Kotlin: 1.9.0
Gradle: 8.6
MongoDB Driver Version: 5.2.0
I believe this issue might be related to desugaring, but I'm not entirely sure how to resolve it. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

This error caused because the SDK version you are using & the version of MongoDb is not matching. I have also encountered with the same issue, adding this code below resolved my issue.
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "META-INF/native-image/**"
    }
}

